# Err too many redirects only on EN language, on ru or be it redirects to /ru/ correctly

Tags: php, .htaccess, redirect

```
<?php
$sites = array(
    "en" => "http://webzp.com.ua/",
    "ru" => "http://webzp.com.ua/ru",
    "be" => "http://webzp.com.ua/be",
    );

// Get 2 char lang code
$lang = substr($_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE'], 0, 2);
// Set default language if a '$lang' version of site is not available
if (!isset($sites[$lang])) 
    {
$lang = ‘en’;
    }
// Finally redirect to desired location
header('Location: ' . $sites[$lang]);
exit ;
?>
```

So on ru or be it works correctly and redirects to /ru/, but on "en" shows error "Too many redirects" please help, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The fact that you are redirecting the user to `http://DOMAIN/lang` doesn't change the value of the variable `HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE` the browser sends.

You can change the code to check for **both** the language in the URL and the value of `HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE`.

You should also think when NOT to redirect the user (otherwise you will have infinite loop, like you have now).

Comment: Sorry, haven`t done thing like that before, could you please make a sample or say where i can read how to do it properly?